# Need hint: Prove that $r = a (\sin t) + b (\cos t)$ is a circle, where $ab \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

"Show that the polar equation $r = a \sin(t) + b \cos(t)$, where $ab \neq 0$, represents a circle, and find its center and radius."

I don't need the answer - I just need a hint to nudge me on. I've tried to tackle it by investigating tangents, completing squares, force-fitting into the formula of a circle, etc., but I can't seem to arrive at the indisputable conclusion that it must be a circle.

This is not homework, by the way. It comes from a Calculus textbook that I am studying on my own. I understand you have no reason to believe me, but if I were taking a real course, I'd bring this to my TA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply either side by $r$, use $r^2=x^2+y^2, r\sin t=y,r\cos t=x$

But we don't need $ab\ne 0$

If $a=0,r=b\cos t\implies r^2=b r\cos t\implies x^2+y^2-bx=0$
$\implies (x-\frac b 2)^2+y^2=(\frac b 2)^2$ is a circle.

If both $a,b$ are $0, r=0\implies x^2+y^2=0$ which is point-circle.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the relations $\sin{t} = \frac{y}{r}$, $\cos{t} = \frac{x}{r}$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ to find a cartesian equation for the circle.

Answer (score 3):

It's been 11 years, I think it's safe to say it doesn't matter anymore if the entire solution is given. I've managed to get through the problem, so if it can help anyone looking for a fuller explanation :

With the equation of a circle being: $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$, let us prove that $r = a\sin(\theta) + b\cos(\theta)$ is that of a circle.

Like always, we have, $x = r\cos(\theta)$ et $y = r\sin(\theta)$ in polar coordinates and $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ in cartesian coordinates.

$r = a\sin(\theta) + b\cos(\theta) $
$r^2 = ar\sin(\theta) + br\cos(\theta)$
$r^2 = ax + by$
$x^2 + y^2 = ax + by$
$x^2 - ax + y^2 - by = 0.$

From this point on, we need to do a completion of the square of $x^2 - ax$ and $y^2 - by$ to be able to get to the equation of the circle aforementioned.

We must add and subtract the term $c = \frac{b'^2}{4a'}$. Where $a'$ and $b'$ are the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x$.

$x^2 - ax$
$x^2 - ax + \frac{a^2}{4} - \frac{a^2}{4}$
We will factorize with the sum-product method in order to make a square exponent appear.
$x(x - \frac{a}{2}) - \frac{-a}{2}(x - \frac{a}{2}) -\frac{a}{4}$
$(x - \frac{a}{2})^2 - \frac{a^2}{4}$

This same method is applied to $y^2 - by$. Now, let's get back to our equations.

$(x - \frac{a}{2})^2 - \frac{a^2}{4} + (y - \frac{b}{2})^2 - \frac{b^2}{4} = 0 $
$(x - \frac{a}{2})^2 + (y - \frac{b}{2})^2 = \frac{a^2}{4} + \frac{b^2}{4}$
$(x - \frac{a}{2})^2 + (y - \frac{b}{2})^2 = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{4}$
$(x - \frac{a}{2})^2 + (y - \frac{b}{2})^2 = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}^2$

We have achieved the equation of the circle, thus proving that $r = a\sin(\theta) + b\cos(\theta)$ is the equation of a circle, with :

$r = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}$
$h = \frac{a}{2}$ and $k = \frac{b}{2}$

Where $(h, k)$ is the center of the circle.

Comment: Thanks for writing this out, it is useful and helpful. +1 I appreciate it! Two relatively minor comments: You should have $$x^2-ax+y^2-by = 0$$, instead of merely  $$x^2-ax+y^2-by,$$ and just above that string of math equations, a theta [in math mode] should be replaced by \theta...[so instead of $theta$ there is $\theta$...]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't revise it well enough apparently before posting

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:**

Compute $x$ and $y$:
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
x&=r\cos(t)&=a\sin(t)\cos(t)+b\cos^2(t)&=\frac{a}{2}\sin(2t)+\frac{b}{2}(1+\cos(2t))\\
y&=r\sin(t)&=a\sin^2(t)+b\sin(t)\cos(t)&=\frac{a}{2}(1-\cos(2t))+\frac{b}{2}\sin(2t)
\end{array}
$$

**Hint 2:**

Therefore, if we set $(b,a)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$, we get
$$
(x,y)=\tfrac12(b,a)+\tfrac12\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;(\cos(2t-\theta),\sin(2t-\theta))
$$

**Answer:** (mouse over to view)

> Thus, the curve is a circle of radius $\frac12\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ centered at $\frac12(b,a)$.